# This CUDA code throws the following error when trying to compile. I changed the matrix dimensions to constants but it still doesn't work

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

[image: CODE FRAGMENT]

**ERRORS:**

```
matrix_mul.cu(35): error: expression must have a constant value
matrix_mul.cu(35): note #2689-D: the value of variable "BX"
(33): here cannot be used as a constant

matrix_mul.cu(35): error: expression must have a constant value
matrix_mul.cu(35): note #2689-D: the value of variable "BY"
(33): here cannot be used as a constant

matrix_mul.cu(35): error: expression must have a constant value
matrix_mul.cu(35): note #2689-D: the value of variable "BX"
(33): here cannot be used as a constant

matrix_mul.cu(35): error: expression must have a constant value
matrix_mul.cu(35): note #2689-D: the value of variable "BY"
(33): here cannot be used as a constant
```

Comment: If you can use C++ it is common to use  a kernel template with e.g. `BX` and `BY` as non-type template parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't post pictures of code.  Please post code as properly formatted text.

Those numbers `BX` and `BY` must be *compile-time-discoverable* constants.

So you would need to do something like this:

```
const unsigned int BX = 32, BY = 32;
```

This obviously has implications for how you size your threadblocks, but you haven't shown any other code.